# getting the sum of values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i really need help in getting the sum of the values of my array, i already tried to research on how to solved this but i end up getting errors like in using array_sum() but end up in array_sum expects 1 parameter to be array, and tried $value3+=$value3 and having a result but not correct, by the way here is my code:

```
var_export($_POST['guests']);
echo "<br />";
foreach($_POST['guests'] As $key1 => $value1){
    foreach($value1 As $key2 => $value2){
        foreach($value2 As $value3){

        }

    }
    echo "Room Type: " . $key1 . " No. of Rooms: " . $key2 . " No. of Guest: " . array_sum($value3) . "<br /> ";

}
```

and here is the result of this:

```
array ( 1 => array ( 2 => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '2', ), ), 2 => array ( 1 => array ( 0 => '4', ), ), )
```

> Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\nation\reservation-form3.php on line 14
>   Room Type: 1 No. of Rooms: 2 No. of Guest:
>
> Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\nation\reservation-form3.php on line 14
>   Room Type: 2 No. of Rooms: 1 No. of Guest:

Comment: by `$value3+=$value3` you mean `$value3=$value3+$value3`...Of course this is a bit confusing, use `*=` instead of `+=`. so `$value3*=2` equal to `$value3=$value3 * 2`

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want so

```
   $_POST['guests'] = array ( 
   // RoomType => ( RoomNum => ( GuestList 
   // though i don't understand why guests in room are array
   // But no. of room can't be zero :) 
   1 => array ( 2 => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '2', ), ), 
   2 => array ( 1 => array ( 0 => '4', ), ), );

echo "<br />";
foreach($_POST['guests'] As $key1 => $value1)          // Loop with RoomType
    foreach($value1 As $key2 => $value2)      // Loop with RoomNum
      echo "Room Type: " . $key1 . 
           " No. of Rooms: " . $key2 . 
           " No. of Guest: " . array_sum($value2) . "<br />";
```

result

```
<br />
Room Type: 1 No. of Rooms: 2 No. of Guest: 3<br />
Room Type: 2 No. of Rooms: 1 No. of Guest: 4<br />
```

Answer (score 3):

Using PHP's `RecursiveArrayIteraor` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class,

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input));
$sum = array_sum(iterator_to_array($it, false));
```

> **Important**: Note that, the second argument in `iterator_to_array()` is `false`, which means while converting the recursive iterator to array 'Do not use array's default keys'. If this is set to `true` (which always is by default), the sub arrays containing members with same keys will overwrite the generating array's members and you will see unexpected results.

If you feed shown array to this as `$input`, `$sum` will be `7`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all your array values with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and then add it to your sum, e.g.

```
$sum = 0;
array_walk_recursive($array,function($v, $k)use(&$sum){
    $sum += $v;
});

echo $sum;
```

So with this you don't even have to bother about the depth of your array.